# Webex and its desktop share feature on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, webex

Any experiences with Webex and its desktop share feature on Ubuntu 11.10?
On Ubuntu 10.10 it works fine with Oracle/Sun Java and Sun Java Plugin. On 11.04, Webex does work, but not the desktop share part.
Can anyone confirm its behavior on 11.10?

Comment: give chrome remote desktop a try.  need chrome/chromium browser obviously

Answer (score 1):

webex says that Ubuntu 11 is not supported. So, you gonna experience many weird sad bugs... the most annoying one is the fact that after a while the sound stops for Ubunters 11. To get it back working again you've got to block/unblock the talker's microphone.

Well i gave up after some talks with Webex support. sad sad sad...